# Getting Pl/sql ora-00909 error, where same code doesn't give any errors on mysql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a page which works great with mysql and php, so I'm trying to use oracle with php in the same page. I'm very new to pl/sql and I have a problem. (code works on mysql by the way)

I get an error (ORA-00909)in the following code sample, what seems to be the problem can anyone tell me?

```
concat(isnull(concat(sihe.V_1_INT, '~'), ''),
        isnull(concat(sihe.V_1_DOUBLE, '~'), ''),
        isnull(concat(sihe.V_1_DATE_1, '~'), ''),
        isnull(sihe.V_1_DATE_2, '')
       ) AS V_OBIS_CODE_VALUE_1,
```

EDIT: mysql version

```
concat(ifnull(concat(`sihe`.`fld_1_int`, '~'), ''),
            ifnull(concat(`sihe`.`fld_1_double`, '~'), ''),
            ifnull(concat(`sihe`.`fld_1_date_time_1`, '~'),
                    ''),
            ifnull(`sihe`.`fld_1_date_time_2`, '')) AS `fld_obis_code_value_1`,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass only two Arguments in Oracle CONCAT function hence you are getting this error 
and isnull is also not supported in oracle

Try the simple example below in oracle,Since oracle internally changes empty string to Nulls you can ignore the null check

```
sihe.v_1_int||'~'||v_1_double||'~'||v_1_date_1||'~'||v_1_date_2 
AS V_OBIS_CODE_VALUE_1
```

**EDIT1:-**

By using COALESCE instead of IFNULL and using CONCAT with only two arguments we can use the below code in MYSQL and ORACLE [link for testing](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/27875)

```
select concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat('string1','~'),
       COALESCE(null,'string2')),'~'),'string3'),'~'),
       'string4') from dual;
```

Comment: should i write this inside a concat?

Comment: The || is also concatination operator in oracle so you don't have to use concat ,also want to know whether you are running same code in mysql and oracle

Comment: By the way, above code sample you provided, what happens if one field comes null? string and null = null. am i wrong?

Comment: it will append ignoring the NULL value unlike mysql where concat will return NULL if any of the string is NULL. check the link below for testing http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/22488

Comment: Oh, in that case you're super right. Oracle is a lot different then mysql then I think it will be. Thanks for the tips cheers

Comment: hmmn updated the answer for using common way for both Oracle and MYSQL for this question

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, really appreciate it. But first snippet looks so much cleaner, I'll stick with that.

Comment: Please use the concatenation operator ('||') instead of nested CONCATs. Per the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators003.htm#SQLRF51156) the CONCAT function should only be used "...in applications that will be moved between environments with differing character sets", i.e. if you have to move code between systems, one using ASCII and the other EBCDIC. That's unusual so PLEASE don't use nested CONCAT calls as they may make people scream "Ia! Ia! Cthulhu fhtagn!!", which may be taken negatively by some people and most of the Elder Gods. Share and enjoy.